# Provisioning Profile issue after switching to new iPhone in XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I was testing my app using an iPhone 6 with XCode 8. But recently I bought a new iPhone 7+ and when I tried to run my app on this device I get the following errors:

[image]

I didn't find a way to add a new device. Inside the developer account it says:

```
Your Developer Program Membership has expired.
Renew your membership to keep your access to Apple Developer Program benefits and services. Once renewed, be sure to agree to your Paid App Agreement in the Agreements, Tax and Banking section of iTunes Connect.
```

But its been expire for 1 year now. And I don't see any options that can help me.

Inside XCode I tried to delete the profile, but it will repair every time.

What are my options to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple developer account which you created in the past has only 1 year of validity. We have to renew it every single year to continue testing out applications in devices. When you do renew your Apple developer ID you will need to add your new iphone 7+ device into your account, download the provisioning profile which would be development for debugging and distribution for uploading the app on app store or TestFlight. So download the respective certificates and replace it with the previous ones in your system.

There is no way other than this i know of which could help you in this matter.